# Overlay scatter plot on map (img)

Tags: python, image, plot

I'm working with a housing dataset for my own learning purposes and I'd like to be able to overlay my plots on top of a map to provide me with a better understanding of the 'hot spots'.

My code is below:

```
housing = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master/datasets/housing/housing.csv')

plt.figure()
housing.plot(x='longitude', y='latitude', kind='scatter', alpha=0.4, 
             s= housing['population']/100, label='population', figsize=(10,7),
             c= 'median_house_value', cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'), colorbar=True, zorder=5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The image I saved as ['California.png'](https://www.formsbirds.com/formhtml/a48b0ecbc6a9c3da67eb/f22f5ccb8a719f8b8a007ca750/bg1.png)

This is what I tried:

```
img=imread('California.png')

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img,zorder=0)
housing.plot(x='longitude', y='latitude', kind='scatter', alpha=0.4, 
             s= housing['population']/100, label='population', figsize=(10,7),
             c= 'median_house_value', cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'), colorbar=True, zorder=5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But this just gives me two plots. I've tried switching the  index around to no avail.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? Thanks.

EDIT: Using the code below by @nbeuchat:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
img=imread('California.png')

plt.imshow(img,zorder=0)
ax = plt.gca()
housing.plot(x='longitude', y='latitude', kind='scatter', alpha=0.4, 
         s= housing['population']/100, label='population', ax=ax,
         c= 'median_house_value', cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'), colorbar=True, 
         zorder=5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new figure by using the dataframe plot function. You should pass the axes on which you want to draw your second plot. One way is to use `gca` to get the current axis.

The following should work (not tested though):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
img=imread('California.png')

plt.imshow(img,zorder=0,extent=[housing['longitude'].min(),housing['longitude'].max(),housing['latitude'].min(),housing['latitude'].max()])
ax = plt.gca()
housing.plot(x='longitude', y='latitude', kind='scatter', alpha=0.4, 
         s= housing['population']/100, label='population', ax=ax,
         c= 'median_house_value', cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'), colorbar=True, 
         zorder=5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

EDIT: using the `extent` parameter of `imshow` with the minimum and maximum values of your longitude and latitude data will scale the image correctly.

Comment: Plot looks odd, scatterplot is small and in the corner.

Comment: imshow does not know what 1px means in terms of latitude/longitude. You need to explicitely set it. You can use the `extent` parameter of `imshow`. I did that a couple of weeks ago, let me check my notebooks

Comment: Doing this would also have the advantage of having the correct x and y tick labels on your plot

Comment: Genius! Thanks a lot, saved me a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 4):

OK, The question is old, but I have a different answer that may be interesting to someone...

I've been working in exactly the same issue. The code that is available at GitHub (https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml.git) does what you need (see 02_end_to_end_machine_learning_project.ipynb).

However, that code uses the California map as an image, and just draws the points on top of it. One alternative is to build a real map, and plot the points on it, without having to read the ma image. To do this, I used the code below. You will need to [install cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html), and if you also want County lines you have to draw them using the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106763/county-boarders-in-cartopy).

In the end, the image generated was this:
[image: Housing prices in California, plotted with Cartopy]

And here is the code I used:

```
# Trying to use a real map
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))

# Creates the map
ca_map = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ca_map.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ca_map.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
ca_map.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
ca_map.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
ca_map.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES, alpha=0.5)
ca_map.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS)
ca_map.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('10m'))

# To add county lines
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader

reader = shpreader.Reader('datasets/housing/countyl010g.shp')
counties = list(reader.geometries())
COUNTIES = cfeature.ShapelyFeature(counties, ccrs.PlateCarree())
ca_map.add_feature(COUNTIES, facecolor='none', edgecolor='gray')

ca_map.xaxis.set_visible(True)
ca_map.yaxis.set_visible(True)

# Plots the data onto map
plt.scatter(housing['longitude'], housing['latitude'], alpha=0.4, 
            s=housing["population"]/100, label="population",
            c=housing['median_house_value'], 
            cmap=plt.get_cmap("jet"), 
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# Colorbar
prices = housing["median_house_value"]
tick_values = np.linspace(prices.min(), prices.max(), 11)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["$%dk"%(round(v/1000)) for v in tick_values], fontsize=14)
cbar.set_label('Median House Value', fontsize=16)

# Plot labels
plt.ylabel("Latitude", fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel("Longitude", fontsize=14)
plt.legend()

save_fig("housing_prices_scatterplot_cartopy")
```

The advantage here is to use a real map, and this code now can be easily changed for whatever part of the world you want to use. Have fun!